# Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 5.6.3)' for 'net5.0'

Tags: c#

This is a question and answer
ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.0-preview.7
The ASP.NET Core Runtime enables you to run existing web/server applications. On Windows, we recommend installing the Hosting Bundle, which includes the .NET Runtime and IIS support.

Full version
6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6
IIS runtime support (ASP.NET Core Module v2)
16.0.21209.0
Downloads for ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.0-preview.7)
OS  Installers  Binaries
Linux       Arm32 | Arm64 | Arm64 Alpine | x64 | x64 Alpine
macOS       Arm64 | x64
Windows Hosting Bundle | x64 | x86  Arm64 | x64 | x86
.NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.0-preview.7
The .NET Desktop Runtime enables you to run existing Windows desktop applications. This release includes the .NET Runtime, you do not need to install it separately.

Full version
6.0.0-preview.7.21378.9
Downloads for .NET 6.0 Desktop Runtime (v6.0.0-preview.7)
OS  Installers  Binaries
Windows Arm64 | x64 | x86
.NET Runtime 6.0.0-preview.7
The .NET Runtime contains just the components needed to run a console app. Typically, you'd also install either the ASP.NET Core Runtime or .NET Desktop Runtime.

Full version
6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19
Downloads for .NET 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.0-preview.7)
OS  Installers  Binaries
Linux       Arm32 | Arm64 | Arm64 Alpine | x64 | x64 Alpine
macOS   Arm64 | x64 Arm64 | x64
Windows Arm64 | x64 | x86   Arm64 | x64 | x86
All dotnet-install scripts

Comment: This is not a question, but a knowledge share. I believe it belongs in a different forum based on Stack Overflow posting standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download new version of .Net

Here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0

Answer (score 0):

Just update your .net core sdk to latest version 6.0

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0